# How often to delete bin and obj files?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

I saw in Kym Phylpotts email suggesting that developers commonly delete the bin and obj directory to solve problems. When and how often do I do this?

Comment: Do you see anyone else asking the same question? I don't see similar questions recently. I've never had to re-create a project because of build errors in my almost 9 years of working on Xamarin Apps. Sounds to me that you don't understand what is going on and the last resort is to re-create the App. How about next time you experience such issues you create a question, with steps to reproduce or proper error description, so we can help you? Ranting here won't help you :)

Comment: You are right, of course. I don't fully understand. I am retired and was not a developer but learning to develop. I chose Xamarin to build mobile apps for my non profit activities. I am in over my head but I want keep trying and will refrain from venting.

Comment: If you want to chat there's the C# discord you can join and get Xamarin help. Maybe that could also be a way to vent and getting some help with the issues you are seeing. https://discord.gg/csharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I face this type of problems when I update visual studio or open few old projects. In must of the time I update the nugets packages and carefully debug the error. I believe this isn't stand alone problem with visual studio. My old projects sometime don't compile even on Android Studio. So, it is always a good to keep your project up to date. For your problem deleteting the bin and obj directory and rebuilding the project will recreate files. This works most of the time. Also try restarting vs several time, update nuget packages and carefully debug the error.